# Error al crear un usuario en Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql

Estoy tratando de crear un usuario en Oracle y me sale el error

> cannot specify temporary tablespace as default tablespace

Esto es lo que estoy tratando de hacer:

```
create user testuser
identified by "test"
default tablespace temp
temporary tablespace ttemp;

-- System Privileges for testuser
grant create any synonym to testuser;
grant create session to testuser;
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO testuser;
-- Object Privileges for testuser
grant select on SYSMAN.TESTORACLE to testuser;
```

He estado leyendo y no puedo encontrar que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: El propio Oracle te está indicando lo que está mal.

No puedes definir un tablespace temporal como el tablespace dónde se crearán los objetos por defecto.

Comment: http://dbaclass.com/article/ora-12910-cannot-specify-temporary-tablespace-as-default-tablespace/